# Computational Theory problem

Tags: computational-number-theory

Is it possible to have a Turing machine that can compute an ODE equation (ordinary differential equation)?. If there is, then can you explain how can it compute.

Answer (score 1):

Any Turing machine can be represented by a system of polynomial ordinary differential equations, $y'(t)=p(t,y)$, with $p$ a polynomial, see [Computability with polynomial differential equations.](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aam.2007.02.003)